# Disabling effects of previous hovers using AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the below HTML code with AngularJS

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-left:60px; text-align:center;">
     <div class="col-xs-1 "  style="margin-left:25px;width:10px; " ng-repeat="image_thumb_id in image_thumbnail_ids track by $index">
            <img class="border-hover-thumbnail" ng-src= "{{image_thumb_id}}"  alt="No Image" ng-mouseover="changeImage(image_thumb_id);" ng-mouseleave="myVar='my-class'" ng-class="myVar">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Lets say 5 images gets displayed as thumbnails,  when I hover over lets say Image 1, a border gets displayed on the hovered image, when I unhover from that image the border is still there which is fine.
But when I hover over another image ,Image 2, there is border around it and when i unhover the border is still there.
What I want is when I hover over Image 2 , the border which appeared on the Image 1(hovering and unhovering) should go away.

Following the CSS code.

```
.border-hover-thumbnail:hover
{
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #FF7F50;*/
  position:static;
  border-color:#FF7F50 #FF7F50;
  border:2px solid gray;
}


.my-class 
{  
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #FF7F50;*/
  position:static;
  border-color:#FF7F50 #FF7F50;
  border:2px solid gray;

}
```

How can I achieve this using AngularJS? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a place were we can see a demo? What you are asking for can be done via jquery, is there a reason why you want it to angular only?

Comment: @ramesh : unfortunately cannot provide you the demo(setup on localhost).I have been using AngularJS throughout the application and want to stick to it.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923111/angular-js-change-class-on-mouseover . should give you idea on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite straightforward. First you use a $scope variable to hold the $index of the currently hovered item(-1 if none). Next is you create an event callback from the ng-mouseover directive to change the currently hovered index item of your list. Lastly, use the ng-class directive to setup the border or any kind of css manipulation your are trying to add on the element by creating a function call to determine the currently hovered index.

[See PLUNKER here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/jplmW6Dh8uaR5xwJMznj?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks ,it works. I was thinking of a similar logic, but could not figure out.