# Dynamically generate CSS margin-top for before/after using Angularjs based on condition

Tags: angularjs

In css

```
 tooltip:after {
                width: 0;
                z-index: 1;
                margin-top: 147px;
                right: -13px;
                top: 15%;
            }

tooltip:before {
            width: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            margin-top: 147px;
            right: -13px;
            top: 15%;
        }
```

In cshtml

```
<div class="tooltip" ng-mouseover="TitleHover()">
```

On mouseover event based on some condition, I need to change before/after margin-top value in AngularJS.

For example: based on condition, I want to change margin-top value to `margin-top:200`. Please assist.

Comment: Your question is answered several different ways here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923111/change-class-on-mouseover-in-directive

Comment: That solution will not work for me. I want things to handle in js file based on few condition i need to change the margin-top value. I am new to angularjs please help with an example. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how those solutions won't work, they are exactly with you are trying to do while enforcing good practices (separation of concerns).. but if you want to use your 'TitleHover()' function, do something like this: <div ng-class="{'moveUp': TitleHover()}"></div> and the moveUp class will have a margin-top: 200px applied to it. The TitleHover() should return true or false whereever you are doing your logic. If it returns true, the 'moveUp' class will be added to the div.

Comment: I dont want to create a separate class(moveUp) for it. I want to override existing tooltip:after/tooltip:before --> margin-top: 200px; in angularjs I mean modifying the pseudo elements after/before something like this  $('.tooltip:after').css({"margin-top": 200}); Or any other solution. Please help

Comment: I don't know why you won't just use a class, it's common practice. Instead of .tooltip, it would be .tooltip--after (which is considered a modifier), this is best practices. That extra class would have the :after property. But if you insist on doing it in a hacky way then look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918458/dynamically-change-a-css-class-properties-with-angularjs